# Cloud Front returns 502 error when pointed to nginx

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront

Does anyone had a problem with cloud front and error 502?

My setup is fairly simple. I just want to put a nginx server running on an instance behind cloud front.

The server is fine, the website works perfectly fine in a browser and got an A from ssllabs.com , but when I access the Cloud Front using xxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net domain, it return 502 error.
The same is happening when I point my domain to CNAME of the Cloud Front.

From what I read this is something to do with certificates but I can't find any solution and lack of any details in the CF logs doesn't help.

**nginx -V**

```
nginx version: nginx/1.14.1
built by gcc 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28) (GCC)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
```

**yum list installed | grep -i nginx**

```
nginx.x86_64                         1:1.14.1-2.34.amzn1           @amzn-updates
```

**ldd which nginx | grep ssl**

```
libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007f057b5bc000)
```

**yum list installed | grep -i openssl**

```
openssl.x86_64                       1:1.0.2k-16.150.amzn1         @amzn-updates
```

NGINX partial configuration:

```
server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

# Certificates
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/cert.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/key.key;

# Ciphers
# ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; #All protocols other than TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 are considered unsafe.

ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# Diffie-Hellman parameter for DHE ciphersuites
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam.pem;

server_tokens off;
```

Cloud Front got below error:

```
x-edge-location - DUB2-C1
cs-method - GET
cs-uri-stem - /
sc-status - 502
x-edge-result-type - Error
cs-protocol - https
ssl-protocol - TLSv1.2
ssl-cipher - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
x-edge-response-result-type - Error
cs-protocol-version - HTTP/2.0
```

The ssl-cipher is configured in NGINX

The certificate chain is correct, checked by sslchecker and using openssl s_client.

Chain:

```
Common name: *.mydomain.com
Common name: COMODO RSA Domain Validation Secure Server CA
Common name: COMODO RSA Certification Authority
```

Cloud Front is configured with:

```
Delivery Method - Web
SSL Certificate - mydomain.com
Custom SSL Client Support - Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI) - (Recommended)
Security Policy - TLSv1.2_2018
Supported HTTP Versions - HTTP/2, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/1.0
IPv6    Disabled
Default Root Object -
Minimum Origin SSL Protocol - TLSv1
Origin Protocol Policy - Match Viewer
Viewer Protocol Policy - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
```

The same thing is happening when I point another Cloud Front to my discourse server that got A+ on ssllabs, but is deployed using docker I haven't changed any nginx config there.

Error.log from nginx

```
2019/09/16 15:34:33 [debug] 10863#0: *109 SSL_do_handshake: -1
2019/09/16 15:34:33 [debug] 10863#0: *109 SSL_get_error: 2
2019/09/16 15:34:33 [debug] 10863#0: *109 reusable connection: 0
2019/09/16 15:34:33 [debug] 10863#0: *109 SSL handshake handler: 0
2019/09/16 15:34:33 [debug] 10863#0: *109 SSL_do_handshake: 1
2019/09/16 15:34:33 [debug] 10863#0: *109 SSL: TLSv1.2, cipher: "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD"
```

When I do `yum check-update` nginx nor ssl appear on the list.

Comment: If you are accessing CloudFront using the dzczcexample.cloudfront.net hostname **and** you have configured the Cache Behavior to whitelist all headers or the `Host` header appears in the whitelist, it doesn't work, by design, and you get a 502.  Does this describe your configuration?

Comment: I use below settings:HTTP Methods - GET, HEAD (Cached by default), Cache Based on Selected Request Headers - None (Improves Caching), 
Object Caching - Use Origin Cache Headers, 
Minimum TTL - 0, 
Maximum TTL - 31536000, 
Default TTL - 86400

Comment: Well, that looks like it should work fine.  Can you provide the value that you are using for the Origin Domain Name?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I won't be able to provide that but if you send me the command you want to run against that domain I'll send you results. The origin domain name is the public DNS name of my ec2 instance i.e. *.REGION.compute.amazonaws.com. I just used Postman and sent a request to it with correct host header and got a correct response.

Comment: Well, there's the problem.  You said *"The certificate chain is correct, checked by sslchecker and using openssl s_client"* but that doesn't add up if you are using the `xxxx.compute.amazonaws.com` hostname -- you would have needed to test *that* in sslchecker since that's not what's on your certificate, and I'm sure you realize it would have failed.  In this case, CloudFront calls foul because your machine has no cert matching the origin domain name.  The origin domain name needs to be `something.example.com` matching the cert on EC2.  Does that make sense?